# Best way of retrieving image from the server

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am newbiee to the backend. I have been working on an app collaborating with a newbiee backend developer. I am working on an application where a user sells/buys a product. I could able to send product the image which taken from the device camera and send it via POST method to database.

Taken image is stored in the database. The question that I have is as follows:

In order to get back this image to the app what method needs to be used? Is it better to get data chunk or image URL in JSON?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend getting the image URL and then using the following code to load the image:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
    NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    if (data == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Uh oh! Couldn't retrieve the image");
        return;
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        //do something with the image such as:
        UIImageView *myImageView.image = image;
    });
});
```